# Iframe with facebook friends list inside it

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there anyway with the Facebook C# API to create an iframe on my website which displays the friends of a facebook user (whos already logged in) using this API?

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website

I'm confused as to whether I need to create a facebook app on facebook first to do this or whether I can just pull it directly using the API.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create Facebook application and then use that in your website together  Facebook C# SDK.

Whenever new FB users visit to your website FB app will ask for necessary permission (in your case access to friends list), if FB user allows access to his friends list then you can read his friends list and display in your web site.